# Alias Django Template Tag

Tags: django, django-templates

So I often have to use something like the following in my Django templates:

```
{% include "conname.html" %}
```

I'd like to be able to instead just have my own tag and only have to type something like

```
{% conname %}
```

Is there an easy way to setup some sort of alias so that when ever the template engine sees the `conname` tag it knows that should actually be a specific include tag?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple, in a module just add the following code (mine are usually called custom_tags.py:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def conname():
    return '''{% include "conname.html" %}'''
```

---

```
#to make it available everywhere (i generally add this to my urls.py
from django.template.loader import add_to_builtins
#this will be aded to all templates
add_to_builtins('custom_tags')
```

---

In your template you would just use `{% conname %}`
Or you could make it more complicated and programatically call `IncludeNode` but that is overkill.

Comment: Just did, let me know if you have questions.

Comment: This gives me a value error: `need more than 1 value to unpack`

Comment: This was almost 3 years ago...  I'm sure it was dependant on an old version of django and python 2x.